# Assembler printing out result

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have this little problem with Assembler. I have to count all the upcase letters written by the user. My program counts very well, I put the result into the AX register. The main problem is, how to put the result out of the AX register into the console? I just have no idea how to do this...

Comment: Nobody can answer this question because it is entirely dependent on the environment you're running your code under. If it's under a real OS then you're probably going to need to pull in printf and then setup stack arguments for it. If it's just bare metal clearly you have to write actual hardware registers to render something on the screen.

Comment: As much as I know I have to decompose the digits and after that I have to add "48" or "30h". I'm not sure how to decompose those digits. I'm using emu8086 to compile if you ment this.

Comment: continually divide your number by 10 (the base) and save the remainder (adding 30h to it) in a buffer. Do this until your number becomes 0. The buffer will then have the decimal digits in reverse. you'll have to reverse the data in the buffer and print out the string. You can avoid the reversing if you store each character into a character buffer starting at the end and moving backwards in memory.